# Pixel limits on bitmaps in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

What are current pixel limits on bitmaps in Flash?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the size increased in Flash 10 to 4,095 x 4,095,
check [Keith Peters' post](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=1426) on it.

Answer (score 1):

For Flash Player 10.1, there is *pixel count limit* of 16,777,215 (see [details](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/496/cpsid_49662.html)).